# Wireless high pings but good signal

Tags: networking, performance, wifi

Could power cables be affecting the wireless router's performance? I've got a great signal but the pings are crazy high for a local network.

[image]

Comment: question is better suited for superuser.com ; can it be that you saturate uplink/downlink of your wireless connection?

Comment: Not likely. I've got one laptop doing a copy and past and it is not even pushing toward 1mbs and no one else was on the wireless at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the background of that image it looks like you have two overlapping networks using the same channel.  If they're not originating from the same access point, you might want to try changing the channel of your network.  From the looks of that image, channel 1 looks like a good bet.

Comment: Could running two wireless networks from the same access point be a bad thing?

Comment: @TiffanyWalker They would cause interference with each other, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have ESET Smart Security Installed, don't you? What is the ping delay with ESET disabled?

What about wired connections, do they work at their optimal performance?

Comment: ESET wouldn't affect pings like this. Just saying.